# Understanding AWS Lambda Limits

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to understand the "[Invoke request body payload size](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html)" limit.
Is this limit for response provided by the lambda function.

My use case:

1. S3 event triggers Lambda function
2. Lambda functions consists of a call to S3 bucket to fetch fetch object. The Object (json file) is expected to be maximum 1GB.
3. Lambda function processes data from json files and makes individual/batch calls to DynamoDB inserting necessary information derived from each json object in file. Each record DynamoDB insertion will be within DynamoDB record limits.
4. Return a "true/success" message at end of function.

Since Memory Allocation can be upto almost 3GB I do not see loading the entire object into memory an issue. However, I am having difficulties understanding "Invoke request body payload size". Is it limited to only request/event that triggers lambda function as well as response returned at the end of function? or does this also imply to external calls made from within lambda as well (e,g fetch huge object from S3 bucket)?

Comment: @Fionn answered your question below. Beware that Lambda also has an execution time limit of 5 minutes. If you JSON file taked to long to download from S3, process and save on Dynamo, the Lambda function could timeout.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only applies to the body passed as the payload in the request body to the `Invoke` action (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html#API_Invoke_RequestSyntax).

It does not limit the body of any calls made within the lambda function